# Declaring dependencies in settings.graddle and build.graddle between Android and Java project

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, gradle-dependencies

I'm trying to declare a dependency between 2 subprojects. My Android java project named 'myapp' is intended to be dependent on my Java project named 'PC'. I followed the instrunctions from the
[official gradle site](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html) by adding    `implementation project(':PC')` in build.gradle, under `dependencies{}`. In settings.gradle I added `include ':'PC'`. After doing both I got error

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :PC.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :PC was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

also tried adding

```
project(':PC').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '..\\user\\PC')
```

to settings.graddle, but that didn't work either, received a syntax error message:

```
Illegal char <:> at index 43:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my libray's setting.gradle file. You can find it from here -> [Click here for the settings.gradle](https://github.com/sambhav2358/BadgeGenerator/blob/main/settings.gradle). As you can see I have added it as a module here at the last line.  Also see my build.gradle where I am adding the project as a module.[Click here to view the file](https://github.com/sambhav2358/BadgeGenerator/blob/main/app/build.gradle).

Comment: This work between 2 Android Projects, but not between a "regular" java project and a Android Project. I'm guessing it's because a Java project not made for Android app is missing some confirguration files, since my PC java project is not using gradle and what not?